# Is there a way to override the empty constructor in a class generated by LINQtoSQL?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

If I have a table in my database called 'Users', there will be a class generated by LINQtoSQL called 'User' with an already declared empty constructor.

What is the best practice if I want to override this constructor and add my own logic to it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default constructor which is generated by the O/R-Designer, calls a partial function called `OnCreated` - so the best practice is not to override the default constructor, but instead implement the partial function `OnCreated` in `MyDataClasses.cs` to initialize items:

```
partial void OnCreated()
{
  Name = "";
}
```

If you are implementing other constructors, always take care to call the default constructor so the classes will be initialized properly - for example entitysets (relations) are constructed in the default constructor.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like you can override the empty constructor. Instead, I would create a method that performs the functionality that you need in the empty constructor and returns the new object.

```
// Add new partial class to extend functionality
public partial class User {

  // Add additional constructor
  public User(int id) {
    ID = id;
  }

  // Add static method to initialize new object
  public User GetNewUser() {
    // functionality
    User user = new User();
    user.Name = "NewName";
    return user;
  }
}
```

Then elsewhere in your code, instead of using the default empty constructor, do one of the following:

```
User user1 = new User(1);
User user2 = User.GetNewUser();
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting DataContext Connection property to 'None' worked for me. Steps below.

Open the dbml -> Right Click Properties -> Update Connection in DataContext properties to 'None'. This will remove the empty constructor from the generated code file. -> Create a new partial class for the DataContext with an empty constructor like below

```
Partial Class MyDataContext    
    Public Sub New()             
        MyBase.New(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ConnectionString, mappingSource)
        OnCreated()    
    End Sub    
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the C# version:

```
public partial class PENCILS_LinqToSql_DataClassesDataContext
{
     public PENCILS_LinqToSql_DataClassesDataContext() : base(ConnectionString(), mappingSource)
    {
    }

    public static String ConnectionString()
    {
        String CS;
        String Key;

        Key = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultConnectionString"].ToString();

        /// Get the actual connection string.
        CS = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Key].ToString();

        return CS;
    }
}
```