# LINQ to SQL default values

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

We all know that Linq to SQL (and SQLmetal/exe) is really a "prototype" quality product (it's missing basic features like schema "refresh" and detection of null columns with default value).

**Is there a way to *automatically* create my .dbml (similar to LINQ to SQL or SQLmetal) AND have it detect `NOT NULL` columns that have a default value?**

Requirements: It needs to be just as "easy" to generate as linq-to-sql or sqlmetal.

---

Clarification of what I ***need*** it for:

I have many tables with `DateCreated` and `DateModified` fields as well as some `bit` and enum-like (`int`) columns with default values; all of which should be and are `not null`.

I will need to regenerate ("refresh") the .dbml after making changes to the database...so (re)setting the Auto-Generate (or [Auto-Sync](http://www.intrepidstudios.com/blog/2009/2/6/using-default-values-in-linq-to-sql.aspx)) property to `True` is not something I really care to be doing nearly every time I update the schema.

The following code (based on [Handling Default Values With LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/01/08/handling-default-values-with-linq-to-sql.aspx)):

```
namespace Project.Data
{
    public partial class ProjectDataContext
    {
        partial void OnCreated()
        {
            if (this.DateCreated == null)
            {
                this.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

doesn't compile (errors with `... does not contain a definition for 'DateCreated' ...`). I really saw *no reason* it should compile...but I gave it a shot anyway. Maybe I just don't understand the context of the code from his example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I ensure Linq to Sql doesn't override or violate non-nullable DB default values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201706/how-do-i-ensure-linq-to-sql-doesnt-override-or-violate-non-nullable-db-default-v)

Comment: That post is 2 years old and hints at the idea that it may one day be supported. I'm looking to see if today is that day.   :-)

Comment: anyone know of progress on this yet?

Comment: There is no progress on this and there will not be as linq2sql is not developing anymore. The code you are showing [is correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1154633/11683) and unfortunately seems to be the only feasible way. It does not work for you because you put the `OnCreated` in the definition of the context class, you need to put it in the entity class.

Answer (score -1):

```
this.DateCreated ?? DateTime.UtcNow
```

?? means if left side is null then use right side

Comment: thats true. But doesn't matter really matter.

Comment: yes. becus the linq object is type of System.Nullable<DateTime>