# Insert/Update column with default values

Tags: linq-to-sql

In order to insert a row which has a default value I've set in the `linq-to-sql` dbml the auto generate values to `true`, but this setting generates an error if I try to update the same column. The error is: `A member that is computed or generated by the database cannot be changed.`I've tried all sorts of combinations in order to make it work. Like setting the auto generated values to `false` and auto sync to `OnInsert`. But none of them worked. Is there any way to make both, insert and update, work?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1120858/532498 ?

Comment: Not a duplicate, this thread is about the update query, the other is about the insert query.

Comment: Sir, did you find a solution? Obviously, it is Linq-to-SQL bug ...