# Converting a LinqToSql DAL to EntityFramework

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I've got an app that is just over 1yr old but it still evolving and will likely revolve more and more around a growing database schema in the near to mid term. The app was written using LinqToSql which has met our needs fairly well. We have run into a few pain points but have worked around them. I would currently consider this app to have fairly minimal database demands.

Now that the EntityFramework appears to be the ORM Microsoft is pushing people towards I'm wondering if it isn't inevitable that we will want to migrate in that direction.

I have heard a lot of good and bad about EntityFramework. So I am wondering if I would be better of taking the plunge now or waiting for v2.0 when VS10 arrives? Any thoughts? Will I lose any functionality if I do it now?

If I were to decide to migrate, can anyone point me at some resources on what is involved?

Thanks!

Comment: Be warned that if this is in a shared environment, it may take you a little while to implement Entity Framework.  I only used Generics, and had a Linq set sitting by, luckily the application was loosely coupled, because I ran into an issue using GoDaddy and Entity at the same time.  I am sticking with Linq for now.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414058/why-does-ef-4-1-not-support-complex-queries-as-well-as-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re wait or change now? Personally, I'd wait (see [Do you think it’s advantageous to switch to Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276433/do-you-think-its-advantageous-to-switch-to-entity-framework)) for VS2010 (as a minimum) - and until the beta comes out I can't check whether the things I use in L2S that EF lacks are implemented yet.

The resources etc question may be a dup of [How to move from Linq 2 SQL to Linq 2 Entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589906/how-to-move-from-linq-2-sql-to-linq-2-entities)?