# AD0.NET Entity Framework 4.0 or Linq-to-SQL

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I am developing a application with asp.net 4.0. My site will be a heavy like more then hundreds of user will be online at a time and lots of content will be there. I have checked both ado.net entity framework 4.0 and Linq-To-SQL with Microsoft.NET Framework 4.0 both are having great improvement over there. I am confused that which one i should use. Performance is one key aspect of my application I don't want to degrade performance of my application via making a bad choice. Could any one will help me on this? Any link or any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any tip.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701952/dump-linq-to-sql-now-that-entity-framework-4-0-has-been-released

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is your friend. I'm sure that you can find a lot of those [threads](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/dc83097e-9c70-4970-93e2-dbc8636eb321).

Comment: Hi, I am talking about ef4 and linq-to-sql with .NET Framework 4.0 not simple ef

Comment: Yes I know. But it will take a while until somebody compares the two. So you can read the old articles and decide based on your knowledge of the new features and the planned application.

Answer (score 1):

Only you can tell which technology you want to invest in, but it's worth noting that Microsoft is investing the VAST majority of its effort in Entity Framework. Linq to SQL is being maintained, but is not getting anywhere near as much attention.

EF4 is a huge leap forward compared to prior versions of EF. The introduction of "Code First" is, in my view, a significant reason to adopt EF over Linq to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to chose the one that you can play better with, from maintenance perspective. In many cases we have based our decision on the factor of the team capability. If most of our team members have enough experience and exposure in X technology or tool, we'll prefer that over another. This way you can maintain your software without stress and also deliver reliable solutions to your customer in less time.

Comment: I know both the things but i want to make a clear choice based on performance.