# Update a record in L2S and L2E

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I was told in L2S, the code for update and insert are the same,

```
db.InsertOnSubmit(row); 
db.SubmitChanges();
```

and L2S will check to see if it is a insert or update and act approprately in the background.

Is that true?

How about L2E? I tested, looks like in L2E it is not like that. Maybe I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LINQ to SQL

```
InsertOnSubmit()
```

*'Adds an entity in a pending insert state to this Table.'*

Whereas

```
SubmitChanges()
```

'*Computes the set of modified objects to be inserted, updated, or deleted, and executes the appropriate commands to implement the changes to the database*.'

So Linq to SQL tracks your changes and then uses SubmitChanges to create the neccessary transactions which will commit the changes to your database.

LINQ to Entites uses

```
SaveChanges()
```

as the objects in Linq to Entites are not using a lock against the record in the database and so need to be saved rather than the changes submitted.

There's a comprehensive list of differences between L2S and L2E in this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589906/how-to-move-from-linq-2-sql-to-linq-2-entities).